# Multiple ember app in one page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to run multiple ember apps on a single page?

I have this sidebar app and then I added a new app to display a modal but the sidebar app was gone. Its only showing one app when I have both app's scripts included.

I tried adding namespace and its still the same.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer that's the thing, no errors. Anyway, trying out more options.